# Lifetime of object which has vacuous initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, object-lifetime

Current draft standard says (previous standards have similar wording) in [[basic.life/1]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1):

> The lifetime of an object or reference is a runtime property of the
> object or reference. An object is said to have non-vacuous
> initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of
> its subobjects is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial
> default constructor. [ Note: Initialization by a trivial copy/move
> constructor is non-vacuous initialization. — end note ] The lifetime
> of an object of type T begins when:
>
> (1.1) storage with the proper
> alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
>
> (1.2) if the object has
> non-vacuous initialization, its initialization is complete,

See this code:

```
alignas(int) char obj[sizeof(int)];
```

Does basic.life/1 mean that here an `int` (and several other types, which has the same or less alignment/size requirements as `int`) has begun its lifetime?

What does this even mean? If an object has begun its lifetime, is it created? [[intro.object/1]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1) says:

> [...] An object is created by a definition ([basic.def]), by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union ([class.union]), or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]) [...]

So, according to this, my `obj` (as an `int`) is not created. But its lifetime as an `int` (and as other, possibly infinite-type vacuously-initializable objects) has started.

I'm confused, can you give a clarification on this?

Comment: `obj` is not an `int`. No ints are created in that expression, only an array of chars (with a specific alignment).

Comment: @Mat: has an `int` started its lifetime at that line, or not? If not, why not? Note, that storage with the proper alignment and size for int is obtained at that line.

Comment: No, why would one have been created? That expression creates an array of chars, forcing the alignment to be the same as for int. No int _object_ is involved at all.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that objects with vacuous initialisation are not initialized with any predictable value ?

Comment: @Mat: not created, but its lifetime has started. Whatever is the difference between these two things... as "The lifetime of an object of type T begins when storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained" clearly true for `int` in that line. Or maybe I misunderstand something.

Comment: @geza: there are **no** int objects in that expression. The int _type_ is mentioned but no variable of that type is declared or otherwise created. Said otherwise, there is no instance of type int in that expression. There is an instance of an array of char that is declared. That's the only object involved.

Comment: @Mat: I know. But according to the quote, it is not necessary. It just talks about storage of proper alignment and size.

Comment: @geza: the quote starts with "The lifetime **of an object or reference**".

Comment: @Christophe Technically, there is no "vacuous initialisation", only object that do not have "non-vacuous initialization".  And these do include some cases where an object has an indeterminate value. But since "non-vacuous initialization" only talks about class and aggregate types, another scalar with initialization, such as `int a = 5;` also does not have non-vacuous initialization.

Comment: @Mat: suppose, that I have a `new(obj) int` afterwards. That clearly creates an `int` object. But before that, `obj` has obtained the necessary storage. According to the first quote, lifetime has already started before `new(obj) int`, as the storage is obtained before. `new(obj) int` just does the initialization.

Comment: @geza: now your question is less confusing, you should have put that up there. Nicol Bolas covers it though.

Comment: @Mat: It's not surprising, as I was confused :) Discussion under the question is very helpful in this case.

Comment: I stand by my previous evaluation that "_The lifetime of an object or reference is a runtime property of the object or reference_" is a train wreck in term of specification, standardisation, formalization

Comment: @curiousguy: I think the whole basic.life/1 section is badly written. See aschepler's version down below. It is much clearer. basic.life/1 is written in a way, that you understand it only if you already know what it means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot begin the lifetime of a object unless the object has been *created*. And [intro.object]/1 defines the only ways in which objects can be created:

> An object is created by a definition (6.1), by a new-expression (8.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a union (12.3), or when a temporary object is created (7.4, 15.2).

The object created by this definition is of type `char[]`. Therefore, that is the only object whose lifetime begins. And no other objects are created by this construct.

To lend credence to this interpretation, the proposal for C++20 [P0593](http://wg21.link/P0593) exists whose primary purpose is to *allow* that very declaration to implicitly create other such objects.

---

Comments:

> The condition in (1.2) still bothers me. Why is it there?

It is there because it cannot say "the initialization is complete" for an object that doesn't undergo initialization.

> suppose, that I have a `new(obj) int` afterwards. That clearly creates an `int` object. But before that, `obj` has obtained the necessary storage.

No, the declaration of `obj` obtained storage for an object of type `char[]`. What obtains storage for the `int` object being created is `new(obj)`. Yes, the placement-new expression obtains storage for the object that it creates. Just like a declaration of a variable obtains storage for the object it creates.

Just because that storage happens to exist already doesn't mean it isn't being obtained.

Comment: Thanks, you (and aschepler) clarified a lot. "The condition in (1.2) still bothers me. Why is it there?". Here, I mean the condition "object has non-vacuous initialization". If an object has no non-vacuous initialization, then lifetime begins immediately after the storage is obtained (as (1.2) doesn't apply). In what case is this condition important? When is it possible, that the storage obtained, but vacuous initialization is not performed (yet)?

Comment: @geza: Vacuous initialization is never "performed"; that's the point of calling it out explicitly. It is only "non-vacuous initialization" that gets performed.

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't understand the "object has non-vacuous initialization" condition. What would be the consequences, if this condition wasn't there? I mean, (1.2) would read as "the initialization of the object is complete".

Comment: @geza: If an object does not undergo initialization, then its initialization is never complete. Therefore, its lifetime would never begin.

Comment: Thinking about this again, (1.2) could read as "if the object has initialization, its initialization is complete". The standard uses the term "non-vacuous" only here, they must have a reason for that. Or should I put another question, as this is already too broad?

Answer (score 5):

I interpret

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when...

to mean

> Given that a program creates an object of `T`, the following describes when that object's lifetime is said to begin...

and not

> If the following conditions are satisfied, then an object of type `T` exists, and its lifetime begins when...

That is, there's an implicit additional condition that the object is "created" in some way described in [intro.object]/1.  But the paragraph [basic.life]1/ does not mean to by itself imply that any object exist, only one of the properties of objects that do exist.

So for your declaration, the text describes the beginning of the lifetimes of one object of type `char[sizeof(int)]` and one or more objects of type `char` (even if the declaration is a statement in a block scope and there is no initialization), but since there is no object of type `int` implied to exist, we won't say anything about the lifetime of such an object.

Comment: That's a plausible explanation. The condition in (1.2) still bothers me. Why is it there?

Comment: @geza So that the lifetime of an object only starts when all of its constructors are called and are done (if there are any).

Comment: @geza It basically says the Static Initialization Order Fiasco is dangerous. An object with static storage duration has storage "for the duration of the program", but if an object of class type with static storage duration needs a constructor call that hasn't even started yet, you can't use that object except in the few specifically allowed ways.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Standard deliberately refrains from requiring that all implementations be suitable for all purposes, it will often be necessary for quality implementations intended for various purposes to guarantee the behavior of code over which the Standard itself would impose no requirements.

If some type `T` supports implicit object creation and a program converts the address of some object to a `T*`, a high-quality implementation which is intended to support low-level programming concepts without requiring special syntax will behave as though such conversion creates an object of type `T` in cases where that would allow the program to have defined behavior, but would not implicitly create such objects is cases where doing so would not be necessary but would instead result in Undefined Behavior by destroying other objects.

Thus, if `float` and `uint32_t` are the same size and have the same alignment requirements, then given e.g.

```
alignas(uint32_t) char obj[sizeof(uint32_t)];

float *fp = (float*)obj;
*fp = 1.0f;
uint32_t *up = (uint32_t*)obj;
```

The initialization of `fp` would create a `float` because that would be needed to make the assignment to `*fp` work.  If `up` will be used in a fashion that would require a `uint32_t` to exist there, the assignment to `up` could create one while destroying the `float` that was there.  If `up` isn't used in such a fashion, but `fp` is used in a way that would require that the `float` still exist, that `float` would still exist.  If both pointers are used in ways that would require that the respective objects still exist, even a quality compiler intended for low-level programming might be incapable of handling that possibility.

Note that implementations which are not particularly suitable for low-level programming may not support the semantics described here.  The authors of the Standard allows compiler writers to support such semantics or not, based upon whether they are necessary for their compilers' intended purposes; unfortunately, there is not as yet any standard way to distinguish compilers that are suitable for such purposes from those that aren't.