# What problem does it solve that for not non-vacuous initialization, lifetime begins before initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17, lifetime

Current draft standard says (previous standards have similar wording) in [[basic.life/1]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1):

> The lifetime of an object or reference is a runtime property of the object or reference. An object is said to have *non-vacuous* initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of its subobjects is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial default constructor. [ Note: Initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is *non-vacuous* initialization. — end note ] The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
>
> (1.1) storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
>
> (1.2) if the object has *non-vacuous* initialization, its initialization is complete

Why is it important here, that the initialization is *non-vacuous*? In other words, why does the lifetime begin before initialization is complete, if the initialization is not *non-vacuous*? What problem does it solve?

What would be the consequences, if (1.2) would read as

> (1.2) if the object has initialization, its initialization is complete

The term *non-vacuous* is only used here, it must have some reason.

---

Note, there was a similar previous question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154744/lifetime-of-object-which-has-vacuous-initialization), but as that question is a little bit too broad (and even I accepted one of the answers), the responses there don't answer this current question.

Comment: *"if the object has initialization"* - always holds in the formal definition the standard has for initialization.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I've added there because of Nicol Bolas's comment: "If an object does not undergo initialization, then its initialization is never complete. Therefore, its lifetime would never begin". Yes, maybe it's not needed. Then (1.2) could read as "(1.2) the initialization of the object is complete".

Comment: @geza It suffers the same issue. Because in some places standard says stuff like "*[dlc.init]: (7.3) — Otherwise, no initialization is performed.*" It could be pretty easily read that object would not begin its lifetime, since the initialization never occurred it would not be completed. I don't think it's possible and designed to have objects that would not begin their lifetime in c++. I think it's meant to work around the issue, that default-initialization can mean no initialization.

Comment: @luk32: Then see my original (1.2): "(1.2) if the object has initialization, its initialization is complete". This mean, that if an object has no initialization, then only (1.1) needs to be true, i.e., after storage is obtained, then lifetime has begun.

Comment: No it would mean that they would never start to live. Since the initialization never completed. Something that is not started cannot complete. I understand that all objects have initialization, but it doesn't have to be performed. Standard literally says you can have default-initialized object for which no initialization was performed, so it has to have initialization.

Comment: @luk32: Hmm, I may misunderstood what you say. Note, I say "the object has initialization", not "type of object has initialization". So (1.2) means in my question, that if an object defined in a way, which needs initialization, then lifetime begins if this initialization is complete. If the object doesn't need initialization, then only (1.1) needs to be true.

Comment: I believe, I understand what you mean, and it's written like that in the standard. Your proposed wording makes it less clear. Now you changed semantics to "*if the object doesn't need initialization*" not "has". Your clause "if object has initialization" is too broad, because there are objects which do have initialization, though no initialization is performed - mentioned in dlc.init 7.3. If you say they don't have initialization, then you'd get questions how they can be default initialized if they don't have initialization?

Comment: @geza BTW "*if an object defined in a way, which needs initialization*" it is "*said to have non-vacuous initialization*" it's exactly covered in current wording and avoids the issue with objects fitting dcl.init 7.3

Comment: @luk32: The standard already not clear: Just see your answer, what you've put emphasis on: "To default-initialize an object of type T means ... no initialization is performed" (So "... initialization means...": "... no initialization"). Anyways, my question is not about wording, or comprehensibility. If we remove "non-vacuous" from (1.2), does anything change? I mean, does this mean some changes to implementations? Is it a real semantic change? If yes, what changes?

Comment: @luk32: your last comment may answer my questions, though. Let me think about it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179460/discussion-between-luk32-and-geza).

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's meant to work around the default initialization that performs no initialization:

> [dlc.init]:
>
> **To default-initialize an object of type T means:**
>
> (7.1) — If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 12), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (16.3.1.3), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution (16.3). The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.
>
> (7.2) — If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
>
> **(7.3) — Otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

I understand that all objects have initialization, but for some objects with default initialization no initialization is performed. Please note that it specifically says that the "*initialization is not performed*", not that it does not exist.

You can have a default-initialized object for which no initialization was performed, thus it could not complete. They would not begin their life time, and with current wording they don't have to wait for this no-init to happen for their inception. Also such object has to have initialization, because it's default-initialized.

IMHO your wording would have a flaw or you understanding would cause logical consequeces for 7.3 of default-inialization definition because such objects would either:

1. Have initialization and would not start to live, because it wasn't performed.
2. Be default-initialized but would have no initialization. I understand it could be confusing.

With current wording it's pretty clear. Maybe some place could explicitly say which objects have initialization or what does it mean to have initialization. I think all do, but I don't have a pragraph for it under my hand.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the Standard quote involving the "non-vacuous initialization" definition and your alternate sentence without "non-vacuous" is that the Standard sentence does allow some cases where an object's lifetime begins before its initialization is complete.

There are three ways (I can think of) an object could possibly be used before its initialization is complete:

1. The object is defined at namespace scope or as a static class data member, and therefore has static storage duration and a name which can be used from nearly any scope.  The object also has dynamic initialization.
2. The object's name is used within its own initializer.
3. The object is accessed via `this` (possibly implicit) within a constructor.

#2 is uncommon, and #3 is always ruled out here as a non-vacuous initialization, so let's look at #1.  #1 is the exact setup for the Static Initialization Order Fiasco, but by the "non-vacuous" wording, the Standard says that some of these cases are actually okay:

```
int f();
int n = f();
int a[3] = {f(), f(), f()};
struct X {};
struct Y { int p; int q[2]; X x; };
Y y = { f(), { f(), f() }, {} };
```

Here all the declared objects have both zero-initialization and dynamic initialization.  They can be used during dynamic initialization of another object with static storage duration defined earlier in the same translation unit (or during their own initializers) because their lifetimes have already begun, and the values of all `int` objects will be zero.  They can be used during dynamic initialization of an object defined in a different translation unit, and the behavior is unspecified, not undefined, with the `int` values being either zero or the return value of the appropriate `f()` expression.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by this: "all the declared objects have both zero-initialization and dynamic initialization"? So, for example, `n` in your example has both initialization? First, it initialized to zero, and then by `f()`?

Comment: @geza Yes. See [basic.start.static]/2: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2

Comment: Thanks, that section does confirm what you say. Now, I fully understand your answer. However, I'm not really convinced that this case is useful. I mean, when is it OK that "the `int` values being either zero or the return value of the appropriate f() expression."? Usually we want to control what happens, it is not enough that in a different translation unit, a variable will be initialized to zero or `f()`, but we don't know which. It doesn't seem much more useful as if it would have been undefined. Or do you know a case where this behavior actually could be useful?

Comment: @geza One example (though possibly not the best design) might be if we have a `void (*log_func)(const std::string& message) = Config::get_default_log_func();`, and the details of `Config` might want to log something like a failure to open a configuration file, which would end up calling some function doing `if (log_func) log_func(message); else std::cerr << message;`. The goal is to use a logging mechanism specified by configuration as soon as possible, but we can still detect if it's not yet (dynamically) initialized.

Comment: Thanks, this behavior can be useful indeed. Note that I've upvoted your answer (it was useful for me, I learned something), but I'll wait for some time to decide which answer to accept (Or maybe I won't accept any unfortunately... I don't have the necessary expertise to decide which answer is the most correct, I'm afraid).

Comment: In C++17, the clause has been amended to (bold emphasis mine): ‘its initialization (if any) is complete **(including vacuous initialization)** ([dcl.init]),’ So this answer is invalid.

Comment: @geza [Initialization is complete and therefore lifetime begins when the *first* initialization is complete](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4802#issuecomment-897389458), that is when *static* initialization is complete for a variable with static or thread storage duration, so before dynamic initialization.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
int i = i;
```

The lifetime of the object `i` refers to begins when evaluating the intializer `i`, so this line of code is well-defined (though `i` will have an indeterminate value, and it is undefined to use the value).

---

Another somewhat meaningful example:

```
struct A {
    int i, j;
    int square()
    {
        return i * i;
    }
};

A a{0, a.square()};
```

This is well-defined. Without the "non-vacuous" limitation, this would be undefined because `a` is used to call a non-static member function before the lifetime of `a` begins.

Comment: Isn't `int i = i;` a non-vacuous initialization?

Comment: `int` is neither a class nor an aggregate.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any real-life, usable examples of this kind of "self initialization"? Because this example doesn't seem to have any importance (I mean, I don't think that the standard have *non-vacuous* to make this example possible).

Comment: Thanks for it, but in my opinion it is not that useful either. At least, I would never do such a thing.