# Is it well defined behavior to store different types in a single block of memory in C++

Tags: c++

I have long wondered whether storing items of different types in a continuous block of memory is well defined by the standard.

I already have experience making homogeneous containers using `malloc` and pointer arithmetic to manage the elements individually.

Now I want to go further, I plan to store several different types contiguously in a single block.

It is important to ignore alternatives such as `variant` or `tag-union` because the purpose is low-level storage to implement interpreters and virtual machines that require direct contact with memory for maximum possible performance.

In the following example I store a `char`, followed by an `int` and finally a `double`.

```
char* block = (char*)malloc(16);

//storage char

(char*) a = block;
*a = 'Z';

//storage int

(int*) b = block+4;

*b = 777;

//storage double

(double*) c = block+8;

*c = 3.1415;

free(block)
```

[image]

This is useful to use in a new interpreter that allows to execute a new programming language where its rules allow instantiating structure objects whose members are defined at run time.

Comment: Yup, should be fine.

Comment: You just described a memory allocator.

Comment: Just make sure each data-item's location follows the alignment-rules for its type, and that the overall allocation is handled via either a `void *` or a `char *`.

Comment: `char* block = malloc(16);` -- this is not C++, it will not compile.

Comment: This is legal starting with C++20 as long as you are using implicit lifetime types.  It should be noted that `malloc` doesn't have to returned aligned memory, so this can cause code that will fail to work on certain architectures.

Comment: That's what structures and classes are all about: Store variables of different type in a collective block of memory. Please use structures and classes instead, then you don't have to worry about things like alignment and padding etc. It will all be handled for you by the compiler.

Comment: FWIW, The C++ ways to make a heterogenous container are: `std::tuple`, `std::some_container_name<std::variant<your_type_set>>`, `std:;some_container<std::any>`

Comment: @NathanOliver [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) says the returned memory alignment must be suitable for any scalar type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Neat, didn't know or I had forgotten about that.

Comment: It is more "complicated" then you think, in C++ you have memory and you have lifetime of objects (also integers/arrays etc). [Taking a byte out of C++ cppcon 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbkQG09grFw). And please forget about malloc, and even new/delete. In C++ use containers (std::vector) or std::make_unique.

Comment: If you don't want to bother with `malloc` and such, you might try `#pragma pack` or `-f-pack-struct` and then define a `struct` with the variables you want inside.

Comment: @PepijnKramer *"forget about malloc, and even new/delete"* That was my knee-jerk reaction too, but I think OP wants to define member layout at runtime.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat AFAIK That can be done in any contiguous memory (not just malloced memory). If I wanted to do this I probably would start with std::make_unique<std::uint8_t[]>. (I don't know exactly if implicit lifetime objects/vector play nice together yet).  Placement new might also be an option (let the runtime figure out all the offsets)

Answer (score 5):

Looks mostly legal, but:

1. You should use `sizeof` and `alignof` to compute the offsets in a portable manner.
2. You need to `std::launder` the pointers. Like this: `std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T *>(block + i))`.
3. If your types are not scalars (not [implicit lifetime types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType), rather), **or** if you're not using C++20 or newer, you must start the object lifetime using `::new((void *)address) T` (note, must not use `std::launder` here yet) (if you preserve the returned pointer from `new`, instead of recomputing it independently, you can drop `launder`).

In practice, you may or may not be able to get away with not doing [2] (especially pre-C++17, where there's no `launder`), and with not doing [3] for trivially constructible types (such as scalars), but technically this would be UB.

Comment: Even before C++20 clarified the rules, I'm pretty sure trivial types just kind of pop into existence as needed.  The only rule for beginning their lifetime is _"when storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained"_ (see [\[basic.life\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.life#1.1)).

Comment: The C++ rules on "object creation" are self-contradictory, while the rules on object lifetime are clear.  Stick to the rules on lifetime.

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you elaborate what rules you're referring to, and where the contradictions are?

Comment: @MilesBudnek It's been a while since I've dealt with it, but C++17 and earlier appear to have a contradiction. Your quote contradicts with [`[intro.object]/1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1), which pre-C++20 doesn't allow implicit object creation. Then there's [P0593R6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#idiomatic-c-code-as-c) (which is what added implicit lifetime stuff to C++20, I think?), and it refers to `[intro.object]/1` as a proof that implicit lifetime wasn't a thing.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Aha! See [Lifetime of object which has vacuous initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154744/lifetime-of-object-which-has-vacuous-initialization): *"You cannot begin the lifetime of a object unless the object has been created. And [intro.object]/1 defines the only ways in which objects can be created"*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Most versions of the C++ Standard contain "An object is a
region of storage" in [intro.object]/1.  But clearly it isn't, because storage can be reused.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat By those rules the standard way of using `malloc` doesn't work at all because it doesn't create any objects.  I believe all of this is the self-contradiction that @BenVoight was referring to and the reason that C++20 contains the changes it does.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Pre-C++20 yes, the common usages of it were illegal. After reading that linked question, I don't consider this a contradiction anymore, just poor wording (`[intro.object]/1` prevents implicit lifetime from being a thing pre-C++20).

Comment: @MilesBudnek: By those (pre-C++20) rules, placement new doesn't work either.  It doesn't create a new region of storage, therefore it can't create a new object, because an object *is* a region of storage.  In fact under those rules, *only* allocation functions create objects, because they create storage.

Comment: @BenVoigt Mhm, the "is a region of storage" seems to have been removed in C++17. So C++17 rules are ok, it's only C++14 and earlier that's broken (also because of lack of `launder`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: But I don't see anyone saying "programs that expect to create objects using malloc are UB in C++17, due to poor wording in that edition".  Rather I see claims about "UB in all C++ editions before C++20".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: You're drawing the wrong conclusion.  From C++98 through C++14, where "an object is a region of storage", it is clear that whether [basic.object] listed it or not, allocation of storage creates objects.  In C++17, for the first time, something above and beyond having storage was needed to have an object.

Comment: But the rules in [basic.life] have always been more specific than [intro.object], and in the specific situations described, the more specific rules are correct (creating an exception to the general overview)

Comment: @BenVoigt *"I don't see anyone saying..."* I'm not saying that either. Pre-C++20, you had to call placement-new on results of malloc. Additionally, pre-C++17 the whole lifetime thing was technically broken because of the "is a region of storage" part (which I think everybody just ignored). *"C++98 through C++14, where "an object is a region of storage", it is clear that whether [basic.object] listed it or not, allocation of storage creates objects"* Hmm, I don't think so. I don't think "specific beats general" applies to the standard. If there's a contradiction, the standard is broken.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: If the rules in the Standard fit neither the actual behavior of compilers nor the tasks that programmers need to accomplish, why should anyone care what they are?

Answer (score 1):

Pre C++20: Eh, maybe? The rules are unclear and contradictory.
In C++20 and later: this is pretty much fine

Before C++20 the rules around object creation and lifetime weren't well written.  Even for something simple like this it's unclear if the result is well-defined (even though it's the normal and expected use of `malloc`):

```
char* a = (char*)malloc(10);
a[0] = 'a';
```

So everyone basically just ignored the exact wording of the standard and made this work, since it clearly *should*.

---

C++20 fixed the wording of the standard by creating a new category of *implicit-lifetime* objects.  These objects must be of *implicit-lifetime* types: scalar types and class types that are aggregates or have a trivial constructor.

`malloc` is now defined to implicitly create objects of *implicit-lifetime* types in the storage that it allocates.  Exactly which types of objects `malloc` implicitly creates is unspecified.  As long as there's some set of types that causes the program to be well-defined, that's the type of objects it creates.

In your original example, if `malloc` created a `char`, an `int`, and a `double` in the region of storage that it returned, then the program would be well-defined, so that's what we say it implicitly did.

---

Keep in mind that all of the above only applies to trivial types.  For anything that requires non-trivial construction you will need to use placement-new to create the object in the storage returned by `malloc`.

Of course, there's no real reason *not* to use placement-new to initialize trivial types as well, so you would probably be better off sidestepping the entire issue by just using placement-new for everything.  For instance, your original example could be rewritten like this to avoid all of these language-lawyery issues:

```
template <typename T>
std::size_t align_for(std::size_t n) {
    return n % alignof(T) == 0 ? 0 : alignof(T) - (n % alignof(T));
}


int main() {
    std::size_t size = 1;  // For the char
    size += align_for<int>(size) + sizeof(int);
    size += align_for<double>(size) + sizeof(double);
    size += align_for<std::string>(size) + sizeof(std::string);
    char* block = reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::malloc(size));
    std::size_t next = 0;
    
    //store char
    char* a = new (block + next) char('Z');
    next += 1;
    
    //store int
    next += align_for<int>(next);
    int* b = new (block + next) int(777);
    next += sizeof(int);
    
    //store double
    next += align_for<double>(next);
    double* c = new (block + next) double(3.1415);
    next += sizeof(double);
    
    //store non-trivial type: std::string
    next += align_for<std::string>(next);
    std::string* d = new (block + next) std::string("hello world");
    next += sizeof(std::string);
    
    //Note: must manually call the destructor of non-trivial types,
    //      but it's also harmless to do so for trivial types as well
    std::destroy_at(a);
    std::destroy_at(b);
    std::destroy_at(c);
    std::destroy_at(d);
    
    std::free(block);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05aab03744694b00)

Note that in this example I have:

1. Used `alignof` and `sizeof` to calculate the size of the buffer and position of the objects within it in a portable way.
2. Used placement-new for everything to ensure objects are properly created and initialized.  This isn't necessary for *implicit-lifetime* types, but it also doesn't hurt and is required for non-trivial types.
3. Explicitly destroyed everything.  Again, this is not necessary for trivial types, but is required otherwise.  It doesn't hurt to explicitly destroy trivial types though (and the calls will likely result in no extra code being generated by the compiler).

Comment: Note that in both clang and gcc, if storage is observed holding a certain bit pattern using one type, a sequence of operations using another type which would leave the storage holding the same bit pattern may retroactively cause the type of the storage to revert to the earlier type.